# Using a symlink for a mountpoint

Tags: mount, symlink, openvz

Is it possible to set a symlink on a mountpoint? I have a mountpoint /vz. When I'm `ln -s /var/lib/vz /vz` the result is, that I have a directory vz in my mountpoint /vz, thus I have `/vz/vz`. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A symbolic link cannot be a mount point.

To do what (I think) you want:

1. Mount the filesystem at `/var/lib/vz` instead of `/vz`.
2. Create a symbolic link at `/vz`.

   ```
   rmdir /vz
   ln -s /var/lib/vz /vz
   ```

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Gonna try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the symlink wrong, you need to run `ln -s /vz /var/lib/vz`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. This doesn't work either :-(.